# Un-pivoting/Stacking a pivot table with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below table in excel (xls):

```
Quarter Q1    Q1    Q1
Year    2013  2014  2015
Company A     A     A
PA      500   300   963
NY      200   150   1500
```

What I would like to create is the below table by using Python Pandas:

```
Quarter  Year State Company Amount
Q1      2013    PA       A    500
Q1      2014    PA       A    300
Q1      2015    PA       A    963
Q1      2013    NY       A    200
Q1      2014    NY       A    150
Q1      2015    NY       A    1500
```

**Edit:**
I have used the below code per @jezrael suggestion:

```
import pandas as p
df = p.read_excel('test.xls')
df = df.set_index('0')
df = df.T.stack().reset_index(name='idx')
df.columns = ['Quarter', 'Year', 'Company', 'State', 'Amount']
df = df[['Quarter', 'Year', 'State', 'Company',  'Amount']]
df = df.sort_values(by=['State'], ascending=['False']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

I kept getting the below error:

```
File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 676, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12216)
KeyError: '0'
```

I have also tried with 0, the same error with `KeyError: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close what you want:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls', header=None, index_col=0)

print df
#            1     2     3
#0                        
#Quarter    Q1    Q1    Q1
#Year     2013  2014  2015
#Company     A     A     A
#PA        500   300   963
#NY        200   150  1500

#set indexes
df = df.T.set_index(['Quarter', 'Year', 'Company'])

#stack and reset index
df = df.stack().reset_index(name='idx')

#rename and reorder columns
df.columns = ['Quarter', 'Year', 'Company', 'State', 'Amount']
df = df[['Quarter', 'Year', 'State', 'Company',  'Amount']]

#sort by column State
df = df.sort_values(by=['State'], ascending=['False']).reset_index(drop=True)
print df
#  Quarter  Year State Company Amount
#0      Q1  2013    NY       A    200
#1      Q1  2014    NY       A    150
#2      Q1  2015    NY       A   1500
#3      Q1  2013    PA       A    500
#4      Q1  2014    PA       A    300
#5      Q1  2015    PA       A    963
```

Comment: instead of `df.set_index(0)` you need `df.set_index('0')` at least at python3.4 and pandas 0.17.0

Comment: Hi both, I have tried the above code with both 0 and '0' since I have Python 3.5 and I kept getting KeyError: 0 and KeyError: '0' after running both codes. Any advice? Thank you again.

Comment: What are column names of input dataframe? You can check it:  `print df.columns`

Comment: Here are the column names: Index(['Quarter', 'Q1', 'Q1.1', 'Q1.2'], dtype='object')

Comment: Solution was chnged. I add function `read_excel` to solution and remove problematic `df.set_index(0)`

Comment: Awesome solution. Thank you so so much.